# How to validate numeric input in jQuery for mobile and web browsers uniformly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, keyboard-events

So I've an input field of type text, and I want to limit the input to numbers only and maybe a decimal point as well. This form will be accessed from desktops and mobile devices as well.

I used the following `JQuery` code:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".number-only", function(event){
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // If the number field already has . then don't allow to enter . again.
        if (event.target.value.search(/\./) > -1 && charCode == 46) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

But it isn't working for mobile browsers as the `keypress` event is not recognized by those browsers. I need a single event or method that works for both types of browsers alike. What are my options here?

Comment: Use `keydown` instead of `keypress`. See the linked duplicate.